# how to retrieve values from multiple queries in a single while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

In the given code I need to print the train-name obtained from query `$q1`, but in the echo statement I provided this is not working. How do I print the **trainname** in the given code?

```
$q1="SELECT st_name FROM tbl_station where st_code='$f'";

$r1=mysql_query($q1);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r1)) 

{

$trainname=$r1['st_name'];

}   

$query="SELECT A.train_no AS AA, A.station_id AS AB, A.arrival AS AC, A.dept AS AD, 

B.station_id AS AE, B.arrival AS AF, B.dept AS AG FROM TIME AS A,TIME AS B WHERE A.train_no 

= B.train_no AND A.station_id ='$f' AND B.station_id ='$t'";

$rs=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 

{

echo "<tr><td>".$row['AA']."</td> <td>".$trainname."</td> <td>" .$row['AC'] ."</td> 

<td>".$row['AD'] . "</td><td>".$row['AE'] . "</td><td>".$row['AF'] . "</td><td>" 

.$row['AG']. "</td><td>"."<a href='Reservation.php'>Click Me</a><tr><td>";

}
```

Comment: What does "code is not working" mean?

Comment: i mean **trainname** is not printing in second while loop..Is there any way to print **trainname** in second while loop??

Comment: On a side note, this code is insecure, you should look into either mysqli or pdo as a replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result row is assigned to the `$row` variable, not the `$r1` variable (which is the query resource):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r1)) 
{  
  $trainname=$row['st_name'];   
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to print **trainname** in second while loop??

Comment: You already do that. It's just initially you were incorrectly assigning a value to the `$trainname` variable; it should work once you implement the above.

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving data from result object, instead you should fetch data from variable row

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r1))

    {

    $trainname=$row['st_name'];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- mysql_fetch_array gives results that require numeric indexes (*This applies to both loops*)

  - the fix is either `$row = mysql_fetch_array($r1, MYSQL_ASSOC)` or `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r1)`
- you are using the results instead of the row. (*This applies to the first loop*)

  - the is `$trainname=$row['st_name'];`

However you have glaring security holes, so you should research mysqli or pdo

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` without specifying the second parameter returns the row as both a numeric and associative array: `array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )`